# Computing volume of ball in $n$ dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $B^n(a)$ denote the closed ball of radius $a$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, centered at $0$. Show that $v(B^n(a))=\lambda_n a^n$ for some constant $\lambda_n$, where $v(X)$ denotes the volume of $X$.

By definition, $v(B^n(a))=\int_{B^n(a)}1$. I thought about using change of variables to compute it. In two dimensions $(n=2)$ this could be done using $R$ and $\theta$, so that the integral is over $0\leq R\leq a$ and $0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$. For $n>2$ I don't know how to compute this volume.

Comment: You can probably generalise http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball